# What are some quality graph libraries for C?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I'm writing some C where I'm going to need to store a very large graph as an adjacency matrix. I was going to hack up a quick graph implementation, but wanted to ask first if there are any good graph libraries for C (not c++) that people like.

I'm going to import the graph in some standard format (probably GML, but thats not a make or break requirement), store it as an adjacency matrix, and then do some computations.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

EDIT: as an FYI, I have no interest in drawing the graph at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/introduction.html). It also has support for reading and writing GML files.